# What is the mechanism for the reaction of acetyl chloride and aniline?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds, amines

I want to devise the synthesis of 1,2-dinitrobenzene without producing a large amount of 1,3 or 1,4 products.

In my synthesis I have a step in which I obtain aniline. I would like to know the mechanism for protecting the amine using $\ce{CH3COCl}$ and triethylamine so I can keep it from reacting in the next step of my synthesis. I'm not really "fluent" with amine chemistry, and I have no good idea at the moment.

If you cannot make picture of mechanism, please explain it with words. I must understand!

Comment: For the mechanism you don't need to be fluent with *amine* chemistry, you just need to know a bit about *carbonyl* chemistry. That said I think the nitration of acetalinide gives predominantly para product.

Comment: After this step I make a sulfonation and after the second nitration. And finally I found my mechanism, I just made a mistake at the begining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The mechanism is just a regular nucleophilic attack of an amine on a carbonyl, with the triethylamine just there to pick up any loose protons at the end of the reaction.